# SQL ORDER BY something else than one of the table's columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with posts in them. Website visitors can upvote or downvote such a post. I want to order a certain sql query by the score of the post, but my `posts` table doesn't have a `score` column - I keep the upvotes and downvotes in a different `votes` table, because that tells me who voted on what. I could add a `score` column to by `posts` table, and update it every time someone votes on a post, but I'd rather not do this, as the score is something I can work out by subtracting the downvotes from the upvotes anyways.

Do you have any suggestions? Or should I just go ahead and add a `score` column to my table?

**Edit**

My `posts` table has a `post_id` column (among other irrelevant columns) and my `votes` table has columns `post_id`, `user_id` and `positive` (the latter is a BOOLEAN, being 1 when the vote is an upvote and 0 when the vote is a downvote).

I can easily determine the score of a post 'by hand', by first querying the number of upvotes of that post, then the number of downvotes, and calculating their difference. However, I would like to query my `posts` table and order by the score of that post, so I want to know how/if I can query the `votes` table in the `ORDER BY` command while querying the `posts` table.

Comment: `I want to know how/if I can query the votes table in the ORDER BY command while querying the posts table.` The short answer is Yes. You do not have to select the score column to order by it. Please see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to create a score column. You can order by the calculated score, as below:

Since you do have the upvotes and downvotes in a different table, you need to join, as Tim Schmelter has explained.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Post p
INNER JOIN Votes v
ON p.PostID = v.PostID
ORDER BY (v.upvotes - v.downvotes);
```

If you want to get the query to perform better, you could add a function-based index for `(v.upvotes - v.downvotes)`.

**EDIT**:
Based on the updated information about the `posts` and the `votes` table, the following query can be used. The score is calculated within an inline view using a `CASE` statement. Then, this inline view is joined with the posts table, ordering the rows by the score. Note that an `INNER JOIN` is used, so only posts that have votes would be listed. To list all posts, a `LEFT JOIN` could be used instead.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        post_id,
        SUM
        (
        CASE 
            WHEN positive = 0 THEN -1
            ELSE 1
        END
        ) score
    FROM votes v
    GROUP BY post_id
) scores
ON p.post_id = scores.post_id
ORDER BY scores.score;
```

Comment: Actually, the upvotes and downvotes are stored in a different `votes` table, as I indicated.

Comment: @timvermeulen . . . Your question is not clear.  Your should edit the question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @DanBracuk Not just beer, feel free to have a grand dinner in my name. Cheers! :-)

Comment: So what if they are stored in a different table.  Your question had to do with sorting query results, not getting them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've learned quite a bit about SQL from your answer and it works perfectly after some minor changes. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to link both tables via `JOIN`. Presuming that the `Score`-table has a column `PostID`:

```
SELECT p.*, Score = s.Upvotes- s.DownVotes
FROM Post p
INNER JOIN Score s
    ON p.PostID = s.PostID
ORDER BY Score
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, your data has a `scores` table with a column for each vote and an indicator of whether it is an up vote or down vote.  If so, you need to aggregate this information and then you can use it for ordering:

```
select p.*, (NumUpVotes - NumDownVotes) as NetVotes
from posts p left outer join
     (select PostId, sum(case when IsUpVote = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as NumUpvotes,
             sum(case when IsDownVote = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as NumDownVotes
      from scores s
      group by PostId
     ) s
     on p.postId = scores.PostId
order by (NumUpVotes - NumDownVotes);
```

You don't specify what database you are using so this uses standard SQL that should work in any database.  You can adapt the logic for your particular data structure.